# Execute Action filter in Controller and Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I had a custom ActionFilter and I want to excecute in Controller for all the actions and for a singular Action with other parameters.

I had this code

```
[CheckPrivilege(Privilege = "Admin;Edit/Admin;View", ReqInternalUser = true, Order = 1)]
[Login(Order = 0)]
public class EjecutivosCuentasController : Controller
{

     [CheckPrivilege(Privilege = "Admin;Edit", ReqInternalUser = true)]
     public ActionResult Edit(long? IdEjecutivo)
     {
         return View();
     }

     [CheckPrivilege(Privilege = "Admin;View", ReqInternalUser = true)]
     public ActionResult Lectura(long? IdEjecutivo)
     {
         return View();
     }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetClients()
    {
       ...
    }

}
```

I need to run the `CheckPrivilege(Privilege = "Admin;Edit/Admin;View", ReqInternalUser = true, Order = 1)` ActionFilter for all the actions and need to run the specific ActionFilters for some actions. 
The problem was when I call the action Edit only call the ActionFilter of the Controller but not the specific for the method.

How I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this is not possible with the same ActionFilter, when you put the ActionFilter in the controller, this injects in all actions this filter, if you have the same ActionFilter in action, this is overwritten. To solve the problem, I create another ActionFilter and inherited the original and I put this in the Action. With this the new is not overwritten with the original.